# Laravel - limit FormRequest to certain parameters

Tags: php, laravel

In a form request class I use a method like this to validate input data.

```
class SignupRequest extends FormRequest
{
...
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'user.email' => 'required_with:user|email',
            'user.domain_name' => 'required_with:user|string',
            'user.password' => 'required_with:user|string|min:8',
            'user.username' => 'required_with:user',
        ];
    }
...
}
```

Later in a controller I use something like this

```
 $data = $request->get('user', []);
 return $this->response($this->userService->create($data, false), 201);
```

I want somehow to write to my **SignupRequest** which fields it should allow to be passed. So when later I get      `$data = $request->get('user', []);` I'm sure there are only allowed fields in it.

Is this possible inside the FormRequest?

P.S. I'm aware of `$request->only(['field1', 'field2', 'field3'])` way, but if I want to limit the fields in `SignupRequest extends FormRequest`. Because if I use `$request->only([...])` in my code several times, I would have to change it several times later. I want to keep it in one place.

Comment: You can alway do $request->only(['field1', 'field2', 'field3']) and this will return an array of the specified request params only.

Comment: Never trust the fields that come from a form, you need always to strip or validate it as @Yasen Slavov said you can request only the specific fields, in your case should be more secure if you request the desired data and store on a new array and then create the user.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/requests#retrieving-input
Scroll down to "Retrieving A Portion Of The Input Data" - use only/except to retrieve data you really want (subset of the input data).

Comment: The `$request->only(['field1', 'field2', 'field3'])` variant works, but if I use the request in several places I need to list the fields again and again. And later if I want to change the list of fields, I must do this in several places.
That's why I ask about how to do this in my `SignupRequest extends FormRequest` to keep the login in one place.

Comment: You can just add a method to the SignupRequest class, something like SignupRequest->getSubsetParams() which returns an array of the required fields, and you can then use $request->getSubsetParams() in all the controller methods that use that request.

Comment: Thanks. That is what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FormRequest is meant to validate your request data, not control them. You could always extract the inputs you need by doing so.

```
$data = $request->only(['user.name', 'user.password']);
```

---

Edit : Based on your comment, you can do something like this. This allows you to store all the field names within a single request to keep them organised and easier to update.

Add this to your `SignupRequest`

```
public function loginData()
{
    return array_only($this->input('user', []), ['username', 'password']);
}
```

Use it in the controller like so

```
$request->loginData();

return $this->response($this->userService->create($request->loginData(), false), 201);
```

Comment: I want to keep the login in one place. This I'd have to potentially use in several places. And if I want to later change the the list of fields, I'd have it to change in several places. That's why I ask about limiting it in the `FormRequest` class.

Comment: @Gruz check my edit on the answer. It should do what you need and keep things the way you desire.

Answer (score 2):

You wouldn't need to do this with the request.

One option would be to do something like:

```
$user = $request->input('user', []);
$data = array_only($user, ['email', 'domain_name', 'password', 'username']);
```

Or you could even inline it:

```
$data = array_only($request->input('user', []), ['email', 'domain_name', 'password', 'username']);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I want to keep the login in one place. This I'd have to potentially use in several places. And if I want to later change the the list of fields, I'd have it to change in several places. That's why I ask about limiting it in the `FormRequest` class.